# How can I grab the last and second to the last values of an Excel table automatically?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table, which you can find below, and I was hoping to calculate the WoW (Week over Week) percentage of the last two rows of the table. The calculation I use for percent change is =(E5/E4)-1

The thing is, this table updates every Friday, adding a new week, so instead of manually changing the formula (next week would be =(E6/E5)-1), I was hoping there would be a more automotive approach (whether it's VBA or formulas).

Essentially, I am trying to pull the Page Views value from the last row of the table and the second to the last row of the table no matter how many records I add.

| Week End Date | Page Views |
| --- | --- |
| 10/22/2021 | 35,604 |
| 10/29/2021 | 22,202 |
| 11/5/2021 | 49,921 |
| 11/12/2021 | 40,202 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INDEX/MATCH will return the last and second to last:

```
=(INDEX(E:E,MATCH(1E+99,E:E))/INDEX(E:E,MATCH(1E+99,E:E)-1))-1
```

Basically:

```
INDEX(E:E,MATCH(1E+99,E:E))
```

Will return the last number in the column and:

```
INDEX(E:E,MATCH(1E+99,E:E)-1)
```

Will return the value one row above the last number in the column

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Scott! What does 1E+99 mean?

Comment: It is an impossibly large number so the Match returns the last number found.

Comment: Nice scott. I was playing around with `LOOKUP()` and just for the sake of an alternative I believe this does the same: `=LOOKUP(1E+99,A:A,B:B)/LOOKUP(MAX(A:A)-7,A:A,B:B)-1`

Comment: @JvdV nice, but that does assume that it is always exactly 7 days (Holidays?) and that there is no time element in the date.  Though mine assumes the data is always sorted correctly.  I do like your LET(SORT()) option as it removes both assumptions.

Comment: Sharp mind! Correct =)

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
=LET(X,SORT(A:B,1,-1),(INDEX(X,2,2)/INDEX(X,3,2))-1)
```

Or:

```
=LOOKUP(MAX(A:A),A:A,B:B)/LOOKUP(MAX(A:A)-7,A:A,B:B)-1
```

[image]